# I accidently killed Mettaton NEO before killing all the required enemies

Tags: undertale

I killed Mettaton NEO and then proceeded to go all the way to Sans and talk to him. I stopped there. I'm trying to finish the Genocide route, and I believe my problem is at Mettaton, where I killed him too early. It says I have "34 left" but lets me proceed to the "New Home" anyways. Is there a way to go back, or do I have to start completely over?

(Note: I also know how to change the game's files, but I have no idea what all the row's values mean. A link to a guide would be GREAT.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you didn't keep your save from before killing Mettaton, your Genocide route has been aborted.

On a positive note, though:  you're currently on track for the Alphys ending.  The only way to get this ending is to kill Mettaton early in Genocide, so if you're planning to get all the endings, you might as well finish this run and retry Genocide next time.

The Undertale wiki has some stuff about save editing, but I suggest you approach it with extreme caution, as you could completely corrupt your save file.

Comment: I thought the trigger for the alphys ending was not attacking mettaton with a full-powered attack?

Comment: @Pyritie You one-shot Mettaton if you're in genocide when you reach him, regardless of if you've cleared Hotland or not.  If you have cleared Hotland, killing Mettaton is the point of no return for Genocide - you can no longer abort, and the most popular boss will attack you outside New Home.  If you haven't cleared Hotland, though, you get the line about not being as evil as MTT thought you were, that you didn't "try very hard", and you're now headed for the Alphys ending.  You'll fight Asgore like any other neutral ending instead of the Genocide boss.